# how to change a RelativeLayout color based on user preference?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android-theme

I have an activity that I want to change color based on user preference.

I have created many styles in styles.xml

```
<style name="Yellow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">$ffff00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffff00</item>
</style>

<style name="Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

It is ok for my toolbar, etc... the problem is that I'd like to change a RelativeLayout background with chosen colorPrimary color. It is getting my default AppTheme color.

oncreate of my activity:

```
setTheme(R.style.Yellow);
```

myactivity.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
```

How can I set myactivity relativelayout bkcolor based on yellow or red color (user will choose one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define color in color.xml resources

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

and set it to view background

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlid);
rl.setBackgroundColor(R.color.read)
```

or create color chooser [like this](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker)

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
```